# Why does my Winsock app sometimes wait at listen() and sometimes at accept()?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, winsock

Hey guys I'm using Visual C++ 2010, trying to write a server/client app using Winsock... I'm not sure why, but sometimes the server waits at the listen() function, and sometimes at the accept().  Just wondering, what is the mechanism of these two functions? Isn't it supposed to wait at listen() until it hears an incoming connection and then proceed to accept()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listen` function puts the socket into listening mode. You have to call this functions only once. Normally, this function returns immediately.

The incoming connections are accepted by calling `accept` function. In the blocking mode (default) it returns only when a new connection is accepted or an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Your observations are faulty. `listen()` is not a blocking call. All it does is put the port into LISTENING state, and that either succeeds or it fails. There's nothing to block for.

It is `accept()` which blocks, waiting for an inbound connection.

Comment: No, `listen()` is a [blocking call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But in most cases it returns immediately.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov OK, it's in the documentation. Do you know under what circumstances this can happen? This is probably impossible unless you do something very esoteric.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov I firmly believe that the documentation is incorrect. `listen()` doesn't need to wait for any network events.

Comment: @EJA yeah, I think that's crap.

Comment: @EJP on the other hand the ReactOS source code seems to be doing stuff that might require blocking. I don't quite follow it but listen issues an IRP to something else before completing. Maybe the Windows network stack has extensibility here.

Comment: @usr Yep. The documentation excerpt reads like boilerplate which has been mindlessly inserted everywhere. There may well be kernel things it has to wait for, but no network events, so it isn't a blocking call within the meaning of the Act. Many system calls have to wait for kernel things, but that doesn't make them all blocking calls.

Comment: @EJP one could claim with the same legitimacy that every instruction might block when it is descheduled and every memory access might page fault over the network.

Comment: Stop splitting hairs, guys :) Every instruction is potentially blocking instruction since CPU might preempt thread right before it. So it being '

Comment: @usr I'm explicitly talking about blocking for network events, which is what the MSDN documentation refers to. Until someone comes up with a plausible *network* event that `listen()` may *block* for, the MSDN documentation must be held to be incorrect.

Comment: Reading between the lines, I'd guess that listen() *might* block if the system is running very low on some resource (it talks about running out of socket descriptors?) so perhaps the OPs code is leaky?

Comment: `WSAEINPROGRESS` has nothing to do with network events; it's returned if an API is called from within the completion routine (`LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE`) of another API (even if both APIs are issued to separate sockets). It's also returned if an API is called from within a blocking hook, that's a Winsock 1.1 thing.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The MSDN says 'Winsock may need to wait for a network event before the call can complete'. As far as I can see this is just a mistake. I have no doubt it performs kernel waits for other reasons.

Comment: @EJP: it seems plausible to me that it might be technically true, in that a network event related to another socket might release the resource that the call is waiting for.  Seems unlikely though, at least under normal circumstances.